# How to Move Project Management site to production server from local

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, publishing, hosting

Right now I am learning Sharepoint 2010. I have developed simple project management site.
Really I don't have any idea about how to move this site to production server(another server)
from my local machine with all the Library documents.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you have. As for the content you can use [site templates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/save-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template-HA101782501.aspx) (save and import it). Also you'll need to deploy all customs WSPs and activate all custom features before using you site.

If it is a publishing site you need [to copy the WSS_Content database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748604.aspx). Still custom features should be activated seperatly